# is the factorial2 function in scipy broken?

Tags: scipy, factorial

```
from scipy.special import factorial2
print(factorial2(-1))
```

In the documentation it says that the above code should return 0, but for me it returns +1. In fact, it returns something for all negative numbers. Is this a bug? I cannot even make sense of this result when taking into account the analytic continuation of the factorial function i.e. considering the various extensions of the factorial function to the negative reals.

Documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial2.html

Python 3.7.6

Scipy 1.4.1

Comment: look at the source.  Behavior when `exact` is True is different.

Comment: I do get the same strange behavior when exact is True, however I have not looked at the source yet, so I will take a look

Comment: Some testing suggests it uses the [formula from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Negative_arguments) for `-1` and zero for all other negative integers. In general, factorial and double factorial are only well-defined for positive numbers (and zero).

Comment: On rereading the code, I see that it treats `-1` different from other negatives.  `1` for `-1` is intentional.  The docs don't match the code.